# always return true from guard

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to figure out a solution for [Problem 27](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/99_questions/21_to_28) of 99 Haskell questions.
Here's how I want it to be:

```
  group :: (Eq a) => [Int] -> [[a]] -> [[[[a]]]]
  group []     _  = []
  group (i:is) xs 
    | sum (i:is) /= length xs = error "invalid arguments"
    | otherwise               = ...
```

An example from the link:

> group [2,2,5] ["aldo","beat","carla","david","evi","flip","gary","hugo","ida"]
>       [[["aldo","beat"],["carla","david"],["evi","flip","gary","hugo","ida"]],...]
>        (altogether 756 solutions)

Thus, I want to firstly check whether the sum of Int list equals to the length String list as above. What I run into is that no matter whether the two values equal or not it always print "invalid arguments". I also tried this:

```
group (i:is) xs 
     | (sum (i:is) == length xs) = ...
     | otherwise                 = error "invalid arguments"
```

still doesn't work
 Any ideas?

**UPDATES**: thanks guys, my carelessness. Here's the recursive part of the function:

```
 group (i:is) xs 
     | (sum (i:is) == length xs) = filter (/= []) $ concatGroups (combinations i xs) (group is xs)
     | otherwise                 = error ("invalid arguments: " ++ show (sum(i:is)) ++ "/=" ++ show(length xs))
```

As you can tell, `group is xs` reduces the sum but not the length so it will always complain when going recursive. I think I will just remove that guard and wish the user would never do it wrong.

Comment: Is your `group` function recursive? And, actually, this is a bad name: there exists another `group` function in `Data.List`.

Comment: Could you include the rest of the function? You're probably breaking the invariant in a recursive call somewhere in the `...` part.

Comment: You're presumably asking for at least one element, ie group [1] []. But what is the length of the second list? And what is the sum of the first?

Comment: @MatveyB.Aksenov the name is from the problem itself but I do not actually use that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To expand on hammar's point, if you change your code to

```
group :: (Eq a) => [Int] -> [[a]] -> [[[[a]]]]
group []     _  = []
group (i:is) xs 
  | sum (i:is) /= length xs = error ("invalid arguments to group: sum "
                                     ++ show (i:is) ++ " /= " ++ show (length xs))
  | otherwise               = ...
```

this will help you track down what is going wrong in the `...` part.